# Use Realm GraphQL Client with a global/shared realm in Realm Cloud

Tags: realm, graphql, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js, realm-cloud

I can successfully use the Realm GraphQL Client with a realm path like `myInstance.us1.cloud.realm.io/~/realmName` but when trying to use a global path, i.e., `myinstance.us1.cloud.realm.io/realmName`, I always get a `502` response from the server.

Any thoughts?

TLDR;

I have been fighting with getting data from a global/shared realm, i.e., no `/~/` in the realm path with no luck. I always get a 502 Bad Gateway in response to executing a query. If I add the `/~/` to the realm path, a connection is established and a new and empty user-specific realm is created (as expected) but then queries fail because the realm is empty (also expected).

Does the GraphQL Service provided by Realm Cloud support connecting to global/shared realms? I’ve skimmed over the source for both the server and client and did not see any specific reason why global/shared would not be supported.

I also tried passing `isQueryBasedSync` to the `GraphQLConfig` which results in a connection and successfully executed query, but the query responses are always empty

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I also get empty responses...

Comment: @rouge Added an answer documenting what I've done so far.

Comment: thanks, I just saw your post after I posted one by myself to the realm-forum: looks like I have the same problem: https://forum.realm.io/t/empty-result-for-query-with-graphql/2258

Answer (score 0):

I got past the `502 Bad Gateway` error using the undocumented API(s) shown below (I had to find them by reading the current code in the `realm-graphql` repo):

```
const credentials = Credentials.usernamePassword(<username>, <password>);
const user = await User.authenticate(credentials, <server>);
const config = await GraphQLConfig.create(user, <realm_name>, undefined, false);
const client = config.createApolloClient();
```

However, I now frequently receive the following error during `GraphQLConfig.create` execution:

> network timeout at: https://.cloud.realm.io/auth

Additionally, I [posted this question on the Realm Forums](https://forums.realm.io/t/use-graphql-client-with-a-global-shared-realm-i-e-no-in-realm-path/2173) that you may want to follow and received the following response:

> Getting a 502 in the GraphQL service usually means you were trying to open a very large Realm that runs into some resourcing limits.

I am still waiting for more information from the Realm team and will update this answer accordingly.